# XmlDocument different after Web API POST request

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web API function

```
//POST api/<controller>
public XmlDocument Post(string data){
    var xmlDoc = XmlDocument();
    ...
    xmlDoc.Save(path);
    return xmlDoc;
}
```

that saves and returns a signed XmlDocument. I have another function that makes a POST request and fetches the XmlDocument.

```
var response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);
var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var xmlDoc = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<XmlDocument>(responseContent);
xmlDoc.Save(path);
```

Both XmlDocument appears similar except the version from the POST request has a missing attribute in the Signature Node.

`<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">`

compared to

`<Signature>`

I have also checked `responseContent` which shows the json response does not contain the attribute for the Signature node as well.

What could be causing the discrepancy between the POST request?